# dynamic binding of chart from database in VS2010 in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, charts

I have to create charts with dynamic datasource, I have a code. It does not show error but the graph is also not visible on runtime.

Here out_table is the name of my table and ADX is one of its column.

code:

```
OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=RS.accdb");
String sqlo = "Select ADX from " + out_table + "";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlo, con1);
myCommand.Connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader myreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
chart1.DataBindTable(myreader, "ADX");
```

Comment: I think your query is not correct in order to run it like you want you need to use count. or you can separately bind x and y members

Comment: Does myreader have data in it? Why are you adding an empty string here: out_table + ""; Did you mean for a semi-colon to be in the quotes as well? You should probably show the view code for your chart if one of the problems is that it's not visible.

Comment: out_table is the name of my table. and the quotes are used because it is the format enable me to use a variable name. I am new to VS2010, can you please tell me how to show you the view code, will a screenshot be ok?

Comment: What are you trying to represent? What are the possible values of the ADX column?

Comment: my table will contain the values of adx corresponding to each day of the month. and the graph will show the change in value over the time period. ADX will be numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for helping me. I have solved this problem, and for others, here is the solution.
here, ds is dataset

```
       OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=RS.accdb");
         String sqlo = "Select * from " + out_table + "";
        OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlo, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds, in_table);
        DataView firstView = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(firstView, "ID", firstView, "ADX");
```