# MS Access: Add data to Chart programatically from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, graph, vba

I'm looking someone who can help me with this issue, that seems very easy to achieve but there is no much information around the internet.

I'm working with MS Access and Visual Basic, and I would like to create a simple bar graph, giving params that I've already gathered from many querys.
In this case: A chart about Litres per Week. I have a query to gather the amount of litres of 4 different weeks. I also provide the information for the X Axis (Last week, Last two weeks, and so on.. ). It would look like this:

[image: Example]

So I'm wondering if this can be done, as well a pie charts and line charts.

I'm aware that this can be easilly done with Excel, but I don't want open another program to read information.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can make graphs straight from MS Access ... and you don't even need VBA

Answer (score 0):

[How to make Charts in MS Access would be my first key word search](http://www.smallbusinesscomputing.com/buyersguide/article.php/3841181/How-to-Make-Charts-in-Microsoft-Access.htm) :)

Then I will check on MSDN for proper tools/properties availability/updates on software and so on.

- [Here is a simple basic tutorial to follow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/a-new-technique-for-adding-charts-in-access-HA001034600.aspx)
- [This is the entire google search that would provide you anything you want to check on the topic.](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=access+charts&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)

Please note the version of MS Access you are using against the tutorials described. In certain versions there are certain changes have been done to the software itself. You are much lucky if it's not 2007...

**EDIT Based on the comments with OP**:

- Since OP has exhaustive/heavy queries, it's recommended to create a `temp` table based on the final query.
- Then temp table can act as a view and become the data source for the Chart
- [dynamic binding of chart from database in VS2010 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916659/dynamic-binding-of-chart-from-database-in-vs2010-in-c-sharp)
- [Bind query as a datasource to MS Access chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). There is a method called `databindtable` which is a chart property. You may use it:

e.g. `chart1.DataBindTable(yoursource,columname)`

This article provies a good sample code.

Comment: Thank you bonCodigo, but like I said. All this information is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to do it programatically, because Wizard and any other Assistant can't handle separate querys.

Comment: Can you please clarify this statement of yours :-)  *"I am looking to do it programmatically, because Wizard and any other Assistant can't handle separate queries"*.... But your title says add data to chart manually...rather contradictory...

Comment: You are right. The problem is that I have the numbers I would like to show, but I have them on VB (after many querys and formulas (interpolations, ratios, etc)).

Comment: @jch I suggest you to have your final query (after interpolations, ratios, cut, diced, sliced, *minsed*,...etc) into a temp table. Then you can load data to the chart from that table straight from MS Access. My doubt here that are you using MS Access at the moment at all? Because it sounds like you are just using VB 6...

Comment: That could be a solution, sounds very good. Yep, I'm using MS Access and this is the "business report center".